# SQL correct the misspelled word without modifying the original value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

When I `SELECT something FROM sometable` there is a field that contains a misspelled word from the `something` column (category). How do I correct it without modifying the <strike>database</strike> table itself? For example, for each thing in `something`, if the value of the thing equals/contains `sophiscate`, select it as `sophisticate`.

Comment: Your question still isn't clear.   Do you just need to know how to specifically correct a single word?   Or do you need an autocorrect-like function that uses a dictionary to correct all misspellings?

Comment: @TabAlleman Sorry for the confusion, but I mentioned "select as". Therefore, I am not looking for a solution for altering/correcting the data themselves

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(ColName, 'Sophiscate', 'Sophisticate') AS ColName FROM SomeTable
```

You could also use a CASE statement if for some reason REPLACE won't work for you.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ColName = 'Sophiscate' THEN 'Sophisticate' ELSE ColName END AS ColName FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: This is perfect but you are about 1 minute late. I gave you a thumbs up. Have a good one.

Comment: Actually... I answered first :) re-check the timestamps

Comment: I accepted your answer instead.  Is there a `CASE` - `WHEN` - `THEN` - `ELSE` solution, such that if `ColName` is `Sophiscate`, select it as `Sophisticate`,  otherwise, stay selecting as the original `ColName`?

Comment: Yes, the same thing could be accomplished that way, though it's a longer syntax.  I'll post a second answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use REPLACE() function like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(somthing,'sophiscate','sophisticate') 
FROM sometable
```

Answer (score 2):

What you may be after is an MDM ([Master Data Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_data_management)) system, where you can have one or more tables, which store mappings between one value and another. You would have (e.g.) "Conformed" values mapping to "unconformed" values for a given data type or variable. So keeping your original data, you create in your output layer, you surface the conformed values in the data either on a view or a table, depending data size.

Microsoft's implementation of this is [Master Data Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633763.aspx) which does far more than I described above.

We use a home grown MDM to map changes or errors in data that we want to be mapped together.

It depends a little on your application / data / data topology, if this is an appropriate solution.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you!